# What is a practical way of tracking expenditures?

Tags: budget, expense-tracking

The goal is to start tracking expenditures, create target limits for each category, and then try to keep to them.  They only way progress can be made with this is if the expenditures are accurately tracked.  What are some ways of doing this in practice?

The financial counselor at the bank provided a list of categories.  When asked how she tracks her expenditures, she giggled and said she doesn't, and she had no suggestions.

Here's one idea I thought of: at the grocery store, put separators on the belt, and pay for the categories in separate transactions.  For example, one could start with "toiletries," then "over the counter medications," next "gifts" (if any), and then all the groceries as such at the end.  I suppose one could try to train oneself to look at the receipts that evening and record the totals for each category in a spreadsheet.

Are there other ways?  What have you seen work well?

A cell phone app would not be practical for this particular family.

Comment: *'Here's one idea I thought of: at the grocery store, put separators on the belt, and pay for the categories in separate transactions'* This is not going to make you very popular with the cashier or the people behind you in line.

Comment: *For example, one could start with "toiletries," then "over the counter medications," next "gifts" (if any), and then all the groceries as such at the end.*  That's highly granular.  IMNSHO way too granular.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant imagine doing this at Walmart 20 years ago, writing five different checks...   They'd kill you, and the judge would rule justifiable homicide.

Comment: @RonJohn - Actually subtotals 20+ years ago was easy because even then, cash registers had a "subtotal" button.  The cashier would read out the subtotal to me and I'd jot it down.

Answer (score 2):

> In this case, there is **no desire to balance the checkbook** at the end of the month -- just to track expenditures.

That simplifies things a bit, and also necessitates a different answer from the one I already gave.  (Please wait 24 hours to accept an answer, because someone else is certain to have a good idea, too.)

> Can you outline a slightly simplified way of updating a spreadsheet every day?

I'd probably do something like this, with a new spreadsheet tab every month
[image]

Many of the categories will have the same dollar amount every month.  Only three will vary.

> And what would it be like if one were to use pencil and paper instead of Excel?

**PAINFUL!!**  There's a *reason* Dan Bricklin invented the electronic spreadsheet...

> What do you call the category that contains clothes and antifreeze?

I call it "Other Stuff"

Answer (score 1):

> For example, one could start with "toiletries," then "over the counter medications," next "gifts" (if any), and then all the groceries as such at the end.

When shopping at Walmart, Kmart, Target, etc that sell **everything**, I asked my wife to split her shopping cart into two separate purchases:

1. all the stuff you buy at a traditional grocery store, and
2. everything else.

In my five years of expense tracking, that's Good Enough.

If you're buying clothes and -- for example -- a lawn mower, then yes that should also be split into two separate purchases.  But clothes and a gallon of antifreeze go on the same purchase.

Beyond utilities, rent, insurance, personal fun money, etc, I've got three expense categories:

- Groceries
- Restaurant/Entertainment
- Miscellaneous (where everything from clothes purchases to antifreeze and minor gift purchases go).

> I suppose one could try to train oneself to look at the receipts that evening and record the totals for each category in a spreadsheet.

Well, yes.  That's **exactly** what **I** do, not wanting Mint, Dave Ramsey, etc linked into my bank.

My "expense tracker" is *part of* my check register spreadsheet.  One tab for the current month's checking account activity, and another tab for the credit card.  All credit card activity is recorded in a separate tab, and is linked to a "pseudo-purchase" in the current month's check register.  That way, at any point in time, you know exactly how much you have left in each of those three budget categories, and **what your month-ending checking account balance will be**.

(My system is home-rolled and has evolved over four years.  I can't explain it will without showing it to you, and I definitely won't post that on the internet...)

Comment: This is great.  This is more or less what I was hoping the bank "financial counselor" would talk about. // In this case, there is no desire to balance the checkbook at the end of the month -- just to track expenditures.  Can you outline a slightly simplified way of updating a spreadsheet every day?  And what would it be like if one were to use pencil and paper instead of Excel? // What do you call the category that contains clothes and antifreeze?

Comment: @aparente001 new answer created.  I hope you do, though, start tracking your checking account balance.  Overdrawing because you forgot a check gets expensive and embarrassing.

Comment: Thanks for both answers.  The example looks quite helpful. // One is supposed to have some savings, no?  Well, the savings could go into a savings account or a CD.  But interest rates are so low, it doesn't seem necessary.  And the bank offers overdraft protection.

Comment: "One is supposed to have some savings, no?" Yes.

Comment: "But interest rates are so low, it doesn't seem necessary." It doesn't seem necessary to... **what**, exactly?  Put the money in a CD, or having savings at all??

Comment: Sorry.  I mean one might as well leave them sitting in the checking account.  And then there is no danger of a bounced check or other type of insufficient funds problem.

Comment: @aparente001 online banks (Ally, Capital One 360, etc) offer rates up around the inflation rate.  This way, you lose **much less** money every year.

Comment: @aparente001 as for "no danger of a bounced check", that's why you balance your checkbook.  It's **trivially easy** now that bank web sites show all transactions.  Combine that with #1 knowing when and how much you get paid, #2 outstanding checks and #3 upcoming bills and you'll never have insufficient funds.

Comment: There is no money coming in except for unemployment benefits.  For the immediate future, the savings are going to need to be drawn from. // The simpler the system, the better, for this case.

Comment: @aparente001 ok.  Note also that since Google Sheets runs on your smartphone, you can track these expenses as you make the purchases.

Comment: Sorry -- as I said, a cell phone app would not be practical for this particular family.

Answer (score 1):

There are various software solutions as well. But the main starting point I'd suggest is - what does your optimal report/output look like?

The categories that are best for you are the ones that fit your life.

One good split is between necessary costs vs. optional costs. And then from there, the level of detail has plus and minus. The plus of more detail is more info (only applies to the info you want), the minus is the additonal time it takes, the additional potential confusion, etc..